# Android Error running app with ImageButton

Tags: android, exception, imagebutton

When trying to add a custom image to a ImageButton, I get the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(3304): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable/btn_default.xml
```

This Works:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_plus" />
```

This does not:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/elec" />
```

On the designer I can see the image fine on the button, but as soon as I try to run it, I get the above error. The elec.png file is in drawable-hdpi.

Burned 3 hours trying to find the problem. Any help really appreciated!

Comment: is elec image is in drawable folder ?

Comment: you need to set button_default.xml file in ImageButton's background.

Comment: You got file not found exception, not related to the imagebutton...check whether the xml is correct or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it turned out that my emulator was somehow corrupted. The code works perfectly on a real device and on a newly generated emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You should also put you image in the `drawable` folder ( + correctly sized version in `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi` to follow Android guidelines )